# Bash: Recreate recursively sub-directories

Tags: bash, recursion, directory

I've got a lot of files in a lot of sub-directories.

I would like to perform some task on them and return the result in a new file, but in an output directory which has the exact same sub-directories as the input.

I try already this:

```
#!/bin/bash

########################################################

# $1 = "../benchmarks/k"
# $2 = Output Folder;
# $3 = Path to access the solver

InputFolder=$1;
OutputFolder=$2;

Solver=$3

mkdir -p $2;

########################################
#
# Send the command on the cluster 
# to run the solver on the instancee.
#
########################################
solveInstance() {

    instance=$1;

#   $3 $instance > $2/$i.out 
}

########################################
#
# Loop on benchmarks folders recursively
#
########################################
loop_folder_recurse() {

    for i in "$1"/*;
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then

            echo "dir: $i"

            mkdir -p "$2/$i";

            loop_folder_recurse "$i"

        elif  [ -f "$i" ]; then

            solveInstance "$i"

        fi

    done
}

########################################
#
# Main of the Bash script.
#
########################################

echo "Dir: $1";

loop_folder_recurse $1

########################################################
```

The problem is my line `mkdir -p "$2/$i";`. `$2` is the name of a directory that we create at the beginning, so there is no problem. But in `$i`, it can be an absolute path and in that case it wants to create all the sub-directories to arrive to the file : Not possible. Or it can contain `..` and same kind of problem appear...

I don't know exactly how to fix this bug :/ I try some things with `sed` but I did not succeed :/

Comment: You may consider using `find -exec`.

Comment: Did you mean if you have a path like `../../../dir1` you want to create just with `dir1` for `$i`

Comment: exactly, that's my problem. I want to create $ouput/dir1/

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail: If that's the case you just use `basename(dir1)` which will return you `dir1` alone, where `dir1` may contain relative paths like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use **find**:

```
for i in `find $1 -type d` # Finds all the subfolders and loop.
do
    mkdir ${i/$1/$2} # Replaces the root with the new root and creates the dir.
done
```

In such a way you recreate the folder structure of $1 in $2. You can even avoid the loop if you use **sed** to replace the old folder path with the new.

Comment: Please don't use `for in $(command substitution)` Please see [Bash Pitfall#1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)